# Is it required to have "area" routevalue on actionlink if the application was grouped into areas?

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have an area called "UserProfile".
And from its Index View I want to call an Action from the root controller (Non-Area).
I used Html.ActionLink("Index", "Home")

When I ran the application the generated url is "/UserProfile/Home/Index" instead of "/Home/Index".

**Root**
View Index.aspx
Controller: App/Controller/HomeController
Path: App/Views/Home

**Area**
View: Index.aspx
Path: App/Areas/UserProfile/Views/User
ActionLink: Html.ActionLink("Index", "Home")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, if you're working with areas you should *always* specify an `Area` in `ActionLink` links, an empty one if you don't want the link to go to a specific area, like this:

```
Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { Area = "" }, new { })
```

This is needed because otherwise, if you don't specify an `Area`, the one where the user is in at the moment will be used.

If you for instance use an `ActionLink` without specifying an `Area` in your `_Layout.cshtml` page, it will work as long as you stay in the root of your Application. From the moment you go into an area though, the link will be generated as `\currentArea\the_rest_of_the_link`, and hence, won't work anymore.

Comment: Mate - you've saved my ass. Big up, dude!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer RouteLink method since it will render it exactly.

```
@Html.RouteLink( 
      "Home Page", 
      "Default", 
      new 
      { 
         Action = "Index", 
         Controller = "Home" 
      } 
)
```

Give it a shot.